# I want to use string array in graphql query parameter using language java

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

```
food(id: String[]): [Food]
```

Here food is my query type. id is my query parameter. I want to fetch multiple data by passing multiple ids.

```
{
  food(id=["1","2"]) {
    name
    colour

  }
}
```

But it is showing error. Could anyone tell me whether it is possible or not, If yes? the how?

Answer (score 0):

The `id` is not properly defined, it should be:

```
food(id: [String]): [Food]
```

In this case I'd name the argument in plural form too, so `ids` instead of `id`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But My question was how should I send the multiple ids in the query parameter. I just want to answer my own question. food(id:"[1,2]"). Through this, we can fetch both ids values